# Get Google Maps Asynch, Null Pointer

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am having issues with `GoogleMap` due to the fact that it gets the map asynchronously using `MapView#getMapAsync`.

I am experiencing a `NullPointerException` due to the `#getMapAsync` not returning in time when my Activity is passing markers to the `GoogleMap` object.

Can this be done synchronously or is there a better solution? Adding it to the fragment bundle would not work for me as the activity may pass the fragment markers after the `#commit()`

`GoogleMapsFragment`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_map, container,
                false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
            initialMarkers = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("markers");
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

                mGoogleMap = googleMap;

                if (mCameraPos != null) {
                    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCameraPos));
                    mCameraPos = null;
                } else {
                    //Set default camera position over the United States.
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891)).zoom(3).build();
                    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                }

            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Activity

```
@OnClick(R.id.loadListOrMapButton)
    public void onClickChangeView() {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if (mLocationListViewFrag.isVisible()) {
            if (mGoogleMapFrag == null) {
                mGoogleMapFrag = new GoogleMapFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mGoogleMapFrag);                
            }

            bListMapButton.setText(getString(R.string.list));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(mLocationListViewFrag).show(mGoogleMapFrag);

        } else {
            bListMapButton.setText(getString(R.string.map));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(mGoogleMapFrag).show(mLocationListViewFrag);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        updateDisplay();
    }
```

UpdateDisplay

```
public void updateDisplay() {
    if (mLocationListViewFrag != null && mLocationListViewFrag.isVisible()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Update Tax Location ListView");
        mLocationListViewFrag.setLocations(mLocations);
    } else if (mGoogleMapFrag != null && mGoogleMapFrag.isVisible()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Update Google Maps Markers");
        //Convert locations to markers to display.
        mGoogleMapFrag.clearMarkers();
        for (LocationObj aLocation : mLocations) {

            mGoogleMapFrag.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(Double.valueOf(aLocation.getLat()), Double.valueOf(aLocation.getLng()))).title(aLocation.getName()));
            mGoogleMapFrag.fitBounds();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we need to see your code...

Comment: @Xoce added the code

Answer (score 1):

You should move the code that handles the markers to be within the `OnMapReadyCallback` (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) that you pass to `#getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback)`.  This will ensure the markers aren't placed until the map is available.

**EDIT** for additional info

Ultimately you have to solve the problem of "what do I do if someone makes `#onClickChangeView` get called when the map isn't ready?"  From a user experience perspective, the `loadListOrMapButton` shouldn't even be shown until the map finishes loading.  You should disable the button by default, then make this button available from within your `OnMapReadyCallback`.  You could either grey out the button (google for "android disable button" for examples) or you could actually hide/show it with `View#setVisibility`.

*Non-recommended approach*

Although I'm hesitant to suggest it, you could instead just check if the `GoogleMap` is ready: from within your `OnMapReadyCallback` set a boolean that your outside activity can check.  Something like

```
private boolean mapIsReady = false;    

mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            // your normal code here

            mapIsReady = true;
        }
    });

public boolean mapIsReady() {
    return mapIsReady;
}
```

Then in the activity

```
@OnClick(R.id.loadListOrMapButton)
public void onClickChangeView() {
     // check for null and all that jazz

     if (mapsFragment.mapIsReady()) {
          // updateDisplay and everything
     } else {
         // make a toast or something asking them to try later.
     } 
}
```

Comment: hmm... but the Activity may pass the `GoogleMapFragment` at anytime even prior to the callback. I added the code above if you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
      android:id="@+id/mapview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:apiKey="@string/google_app_id"
      android:clickable="true">
  </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(33.8650, 151.2094);
    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this); /* initialize method should     be called when we are not sure that map will be loaded before using it. It initialises the map.*/

        mapView.onCreate(null); 
        mapView.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).draggable(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use a mapfragment to hold the `MapView` as I am showing and hiding the fragments.

Comment: MapView acts like a view and MapFragment acts as a Fragment. There is nothing like you need a MapFragment to Hold a MapView. Both are used to display map. You can Hold a MapView or MapFragment in any layout like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.